# The bind9 forward zone more flexible than reverse zone file?

Tags: dns, bind9

My local network is 192.168.0.1, but of course the cable modem is 192.168.100.1.  In my local DNS server I can fudge a lookup for my private domain of 'dd.org', for example 'cable.dd.org' as 192.168.100.1, and it works.  However, the reverse lookup in a defined range of 192.168.0 doing 100.1 for cable.dd.org of course fails because the reverse lookup file is based on 192.168.0 not 192.168.100.  The question is why is the forward lookup file more permissive?  Is this by design or simply because cable.dd.org is inclusive of any ip that is mapped to something in dd.org?  To get this flexibility do use create reverse file that is not limited to the last octet?  but to the last two octets?  I solved it by setting up two reverse files for 192.168.0 and 192.168.100 because this seemed straight forward.  But wonder if that is best or most elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you should create a zone file that is broad enough to encompass the entire range you wish to define.  The alternative is to define multiple smaller zones for the specific CIDR ranges you wish to cover.  Here is one possible sample zone file that covers the `168.192.in-addr.arpa` zone:

```
; reverse DNS zone for IP range 192.168.0.0/16
 
$ORIGIN 168.192.in-addr.arpa.

$TTL    300

@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. hostmaster.ns.example.com.  (
                                202105260       ; Serial
                                3600            ; Refresh
                                900             ; Retry
                                3600000         ; Expire
                                300 )           ; Minimum
        IN      NS      ns.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

100.1   IN PTR          cable.dd.org.
0.5     IN PTR          192-168-0-5.dd.org.
```

Such a zone file could also be structured:

```
; reverse DNS zone for IP range 192.168.0.0/16

$ORIGIN 168.192.in-addr.arpa.

$TTL    300

@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. hostmaster.ns.example.com.  (
                                202105260       ; Serial
                                3600            ; Refresh
                                900             ; Retry
                                3600000         ; Expire
                                300 )           ; Minimum
        IN      NS      ns.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
5       IN PTR          192-168-0-5.dd.org.

$ORIGIN 100.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    
1       IN PTR          cable.dd.org.
```